# How to get eclipse workspace path

Tags: java, eclipse, path, workspace

I'm trying to get the workspace path of my eclipse.The result I want is

> D:\MyWorkspace.

I have searched a lot and found this.

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString()
```

But it returns the following.

```
D:/runtime-EclipseApplication
```

Any help?

Comment: If you can tell what is your motive behind fetching the path then you might get better answers or some other alternatives to fetch the workspace path.

Answer (score 1):

`D:/runtime-EclipseApplication` is the workspace that you are using when you do `Run As > Eclipse Application`. So this is the correct value for the workspace when your application is running. The value is configured in the `Run Configuration` dialog.

If you write a plugin and install it in to your Eclipse then you will get the location of your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace is stored in /path_to_eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs simplest way is to parse this file. It has simply config format "variable=value/n".